# Does memsql really support Ranking Functions?

Tags: sql, window-functions, singlestore

http://docs.memsql.com/5.0/concepts/window_functions/

I checked the doc linked above and came up with several possible SQL functions but had no luck with any of them. These are just a few:

```
select row_number() from test;
select row_number() over (order by _id) from test;
select row_number() over {order by _id} from test;
select row_number() over order by _id from test;
select row_number() over (order by _id) as row_num from test;
select row_number over order by _id as row_num from test;
```

All give me ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

MemSQL version is 5.5.8

And of course `select _id from test;` works fine?

So what is the exact syntax to use? Or is there actually no such thing in MemSQL?

Comment: Both #2 & #5 are valid SQL and should be supported based on the linked doc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version string you see is a mysql compatibility version, which I assume you got by doing `SELECT version();`. To correctly check your MemSQL version, use `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'memsql_version';`.

Window functions are new in MemSQL 5, leading me to believe you aren't running MemSQL 5. That wouldn't be odd, as 5 is still in beta (as of 2016-03-16). You can get the beta [here](http://blog.memsql.com/introducing-memsql-5-beta/).

In his reply to your question, dnoeth correctly states that queries #2 and #5 are valid. For due diligence, I have ran these queries against my local build of MemSQL, and both of them work.

```
memsql> create table test(_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

memsql> insert into test values (1), (2), (3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

memsql> select row_number() over (order by _id) from test;
+----------------------------------+
| row_number() over (order by _id) |
+----------------------------------+
|                                1 |
|                                2 |
|                                3 |
+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

memsql> select row_number() over (order by _id) as row_num from test;
+---------+
| row_num |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
|       3 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

memsql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'memsql_version';
+----------------+-------+
| Variable_name  | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| memsql_version | 5.0   |
+----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, my memsql version turns out to be 4.1.2.